# Query for sub-document when key is numeric?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am struggling to write a mongodb query that reaches into a sub-document for a key that is numeric.

My documents are like...

```
/* The collection m-plan contains the MfgPlan records */
rs0:SECONDARY> db['plan'].find( { $and: [ {displayId: 'MP-1'}, { version: 5 } ] } ).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cda661b93dbc10001903d52"),
    "activities" : {
        "5cda66c293dbc10001903d57" : [
            "5b198d8c794c820001ee3c25",
            "5b198da4794c820001ee3c2e"
        ],
        "5c86f61f42c68d000165559d" : [
            "5cda66c293dbc10001903d57"
        ],
        "5b198d8c794c820001ee3c25" : [ ],
        "5b198da4794c820001ee3c2e" : [ ]
    },
    "createdByUser" : "rkuhar",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2021-03-14T06:54:19.154Z"),
    "displayId" : "MP-1",
    "displayName" : "Obliterator 9000"
    "revisionId" : ObjectId("5cda66c293dbc10001903d59"),
    "version" : 5
}
```

But my attempts to locate, like "5c86f61f42c68d000165559d" get rejected by the shell.

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db['plan'].find( { activities.5c86f61f42c68d000165559d: { $exists: true } } ).pretty();
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal :
@(shell):1:33
rs0:SECONDARY> db['plan'].find( { activities."5c86f61f42c68d000165559d": { $exists: true } } ).pretty();
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
@(shell):1:33
```

How do I query for the existence of a key if the key is numeric?

Comment: just try `{ "activities.5c86f61f42c68d000165559d": { $exists: true } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use dot notation, you need to wrap the property in quotes. Like so:

```js
db['plan'].find( { "activities.5c86f61f42c68d000165559d": { $exists: true } } ).pretty();
```